# Deserializar JSON

Tags: c#, json, api

Consigo fazer o POST desta informação:

```
{
    "Nritem": 1,
    "Cdprevenda": 3,
    "Cdproduto": 7,
    "Decomplitem": "",
    "Descricao": "Depilação",
    "Dtcadastro": "2015-11-27T13:53:35.120Z",
    "Flsituacao": 1,
    "Md5": "",
    "Qtproduto": 18,
    "Totalizador": "01T1700",
    "Unidade": "UN",
    "Vltabela": 50,
    "Vlunitario": 50,
}
```

Mas se colocar entre `[]` aparece esta mensagem:

```
"itemprevenda":[
  "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'PreVendaWebAPI.Models.Itemprevenda' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."]
```

API que faz o POST:

```
// POST: api/Itemprevendas
    [ResponseType(typeof(Itemprevenda))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda itemprevenda)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        //  Implementar o Cditemprevenda e o Nritem automaticamente
        decimal cd = await GetMaiorCod();
        decimal nr = await GetMaiorNr(itemprevenda.Cdprevenda);

        itemprevenda.Cditemprevenda = cd;
        itemprevenda.Nritem = nr;
        //  *******************************************************

        db.Itemprevenda.Add(itemprevenda);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (ItemprevendaExists(itemprevenda.Cditemprevenda))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = itemprevenda.Cditemprevenda }, itemprevenda);
    }
```

Itemprevenda:

```
public partial class Itemprevenda
{
    public decimal Cditemprevenda { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdprevenda { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdproduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Nritem { get; set; }
    public decimal Qtproduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Vltabela { get; set; }
    public decimal Vldesconto { get; set; }
    public decimal Vlacrescimo { get; set; }
    public decimal Vlunitario { get; set; }
    public int Flsituacao { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Dtcadastro { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Unidade { get; set; }
    public string Totalizador { get; set; }
    public byte[] Md5 { get; set; }
    public string Decomplitem { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdvendedor { get; set; }
    public decimal Vltotal { get; set; }
}
```

Como faço para deserializar este JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Forma correta:**

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda itemprevenda){}
```

Quando o Json está entre [ ] a API entende que é uma lista de objetos, então tem que dizer que Itemprevenda é List desta forma `List<Itemprevenda>`.
E agora só fazer um `foreach` e percorrer a lista.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize o JavaScriptSerializer presente no namespace

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization;
```

O mesmo possui um método chamado Deserialize onde voce passa o objeto JSON e o tipo no qual o JSON será convertido.

Ex:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
meuTipo minhaVariavel = serializer.Deserialize(stringJson, meuTipo);
```

Comment: meuTipo seria o tipo que estou passando para deserializar: Itemprevenda? E stringJson é o formato que vai ser deserializado?

Comment: Exato, o meuTipo seria o Itemprevenda.

stringJson é a string que contem o json que voce quer deserializar.

Comment: Mas não tem uma _string_ com o JSON. O que eu tenho é Itemprevenda: `PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda itemprevenda)`

Comment: Então voce quer serializar os dados? O que exatamente voce precisa?

Comment: Estou passando dados em JSON para a API e preciso descerializar para fazer o POST de objeto por objeto.

Comment: Mas o seu objeto já não está "deserializado" ? Me explica melhor o fluxo da sua lógica (passo a passo) e o objetivo final de todo o processo, por favor...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33593/discussion-between-andre-santarosa-and-leopiazzoli).

Answer (score 2):

Bom, eu faria uma estrutura assim:

O JSON:

```
string seujson=
@"{""data"":[{""Cditemprevenda"":""1"",""Cdproduto"":""8""},{""Cditemprevenda"":""2"",""Cdproduto"":""9""}, {""Cditemprevenda"":""3"",""Cdproduto"":""10""}]}";
```

As classes:

```
public class Itemprevenda
{

     public List<Item> Items {get;set;}
}

public class Item
{
    public string Cditemprevenda {get;set;}
    public string Cdproduto {get;set;}
}
Itemprevenda item = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Itemprevenda>(seujson);
```

Para recuperar:

```
foreach(var json in item.Items)
{
   Console.WriteLine("CdItem: {0}, CdProduto: {1}",json.Cditemprevenda ,json.Cdproduto );
}
```

Comment: Só que o JSON vai vir através da URL do navegador, eu não vou defini-la no escopo do código com `string seujson=
@...`. Como faço pra passar esta informação para a classe, dentro do **seujson**.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIÇÃO**
Não tinha me atendado ao fato da deserialização ser implícita. para receber mais de um objeto do tipo `Itemprevenda` você deverá modificar a assinatura do seu método de `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda itemprevenda)` para `public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda[] itemprevenda)`. Note que foi adicionado `[]` após o tipo `Itemprevenda`.

Fazendo esta modificação o seu `JSON` deverá ser enviado da seguinte forma para a sua API:

```
"[{
        "Nritem": 1,
        "Cdprevenda": 3,
        "Cdproduto": 7,
        "Decomplitem": "",
        "Descricao": "Depilação",
        "Dtcadastro": "2015-11-27T13:53:35.120Z",
        "Flsituacao": 1,
        "Md5": "",
        "Qtproduto": 18,
        "Totalizador": "01T1700",
        "Unidade": "UN",
        "Vltabela": 50,
        "Vlunitario": 50,
    }, {
        "Nritem": 2,
        "Cdprevenda": 4,
        "Cdproduto": 8,
        "Decomplitem": "",
        "Descricao": "Depilação 2",
        "Dtcadastro": "2015-11-27T13:53:35.120Z",
        "Flsituacao": 1,
        "Md5": "",
        "Qtproduto": 18,
        "Totalizador": "01T1700",
        "Unidade": "UN",
        "Vltabela": 50,
        "Vlunitario": 50,
    }]";
```

O seu `JSON` deve ser enviado sem um `label` para o array, pois caso contrário o ocorrerá um erro na deserialização do `JSON`.

**Antigo:**

A questão é que você utilizando sem o `[]` ele considera somente um item e colocando o `[]` ele considera um vetor, `array` de itens.

Para fazer isso o seu modelo deveria conter um array `itemprevenda` com os mesmos atributos que o seu JSON.

Tente deixar a sua classe modelo semelhante à isso:

```
///Essa classe será a classe que conterá a sua lista de itens
///de pré venda.
public class Modelo {
    public Itemprevenda[] itemprevenda { get; set; }
}

public partial class Itemprevenda
{
    public decimal Cditemprevenda { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdprevenda { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdproduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Nritem { get; set; }
    public decimal Qtproduto { get; set; }
    public decimal Vltabela { get; set; }
    public decimal Vldesconto { get; set; }
    public decimal Vlacrescimo { get; set; }
    public decimal Vlunitario { get; set; }
    public int Flsituacao { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Dtcadastro { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Unidade { get; set; }
    public string Totalizador { get; set; }
    public byte[] Md5 { get; set; }
    public string Decomplitem { get; set; }
    public decimal Cdvendedor { get; set; }
    public decimal Vltotal { get; set; }
}

string seujson = "{
    "itemprevenda": [{
        "Nritem": 1,
        "Cdprevenda": 3,
        "Cdproduto": 7,
        "Decomplitem": "",
        "Descricao": "Depilação",
        "Dtcadastro": "2015-11-27T13:53:35.120Z",
        "Flsituacao": 1,
        "Md5": "",
        "Qtproduto": 18,
        "Totalizador": "01T1700",
        "Unidade": "UN",
        "Vltabela": 50,
        "Vlunitario": 50,
    }]
}";

/*
  Realiza a deserialização do JSON para um objeto do tipo "Modelo"
  que contém o array de Itemprevenda. Modelo com 'M' maiúsculo é a
  classe e com 'm' minúsculo é a variável.
*/
Modelo modelo = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Modelo>(seujson);
```

Como você deseja receber uma série, `array`, de objetos `Itemprevenda` você deve ter uma classe, nesse exemplo a classe `Modelo`, para conter esse `array`.

Isso deverá solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Pode explicar o que está sendo feito nesta implementação? O que seria **Modelo** e **modelo**? E o que tenho que passar em **seujson**?

Comment: @leopiazzoli modifiquei a resposta para tentar esclarecer

Comment: Tem que passar uma _string_ para **seujson** certo? Mas as informações que são passadas para a API são do tipo Itemprevenda. `PostItemprevenda(Itemprevenda itemprevenda)`.

Comment: Não tinha me antedado para isso. Já modifiquei a resposta.